# Dynamic filtering in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I have just started learning ShinyApp and am trying to create a table whose values can dynamically filtered.

**The result I want**

```
<filter>GlassSupplier Supplier1
WindowType        AverageBreakageRate
Aluminum                  3.63
Wood                      7.22
```

**The result I get**.

```
<filter>GlassSupplier Supplier1
WindowType        AverageBreakageRate
Aluminum                  2.815
Vinyl                     6.165
Wood                      7.22
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EtL2.png)

My code creates a table but does not filter based on the select input selection.  Also is there a way to add an action button, so the table reflects changes due to a new select input parameter only when the action button is hit?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             selectInput(inputId = "table",
                                         label = "Choose a Supplier",
                                         "Names"),
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel",
                          tableOutput("myTable")
                )))

server <- function(input, output,session) 
{
  GlassSupplier <- c('Supplier 1','Supplier 2','Supplier 1','Supplier 4','Supplier 2')
  WindowType <- c('Wood','Vinyl','Aluminum','Aluminum','Vinyl')
  BreakageRate <- c(7.22,6.33,3.63,2,6)
  df<- data.frame(GlassSupplier,WindowType,BreakageRate)
   data <- reactive({
    req(input$table)
    dframe <- df %>%  group_by(WindowType) %>% summarise(BrkRate = mean(BreakageRate))
  })
  
  #Update SelectInput Dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "table", choices = df$GlassSupplier)
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
    data()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Image of data is not useful to help you.  If you want someone to help you, please post the data in the question so that someone can copy and work with your code.  You can use `dput()` to get the data in console and post it in the question.

Comment: thank you for your feedback I have made changes to the code and the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `filter`.  For the `actionButton` to work, just change the `reactive()` to `eventReactive()` object.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             selectInput(inputId = "table",
                                         label = "Choose a Supplier",
                                         "Names"),
                             actionButton(inputId = "btn",label="Update")
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel",
                          tableOutput("myTable")
                )))

server <- function(input, output,session)
{
  GlassSupplier <- c('Supplier 1','Supplier 2','Supplier 1','Supplier 4','Supplier 2')
  WindowType <- c('Wood','Vinyl','Aluminum','Aluminum','Vinyl')
  BreakageRate <- c(7.22,6.33,3.63,2,6)
  df<- data.frame(GlassSupplier,WindowType,BreakageRate)
  data <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    req(input$table)
    df %>% dplyr::filter(GlassSupplier %in% input$table) %>%
      group_by(WindowType) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(BrkRate = mean(BreakageRate))
  })

  #Update SelectInput Dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "table", choices = df$GlassSupplier)
  })

  output$myTable = renderTable({
    data()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: is there a way to add an action button so the table's values so not change on changing the filter ?

Comment: hey, thank you so much. I figured that part. Can you please show me how to remove an object created with an action button?

Comment: As this question does not have an actionButton, please modify your question or ask a new question to show which object you want to delete.

Comment: Hi YBS, I just posted a question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059229/multiple-tabs-in-shinyapp>. Can you please help me with it?