# Multiple tabs in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

This code gives me one tab. I would like to be able to add more tabs to it to make some plots, use the aggregate function may be. I tired to add a second `tabPanel(` object inside my `tabsetPanel(` but did not work.

I will be obliged if someone could help me with this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Table", fluid = TRUE,
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             selectInput(inputId = "table",
                                         label = "Choose a Supplier",
                                         "Names"),
                             actionButton(inputId = "btn",label="Update")
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel",
                          tableOutput("myTable")
                )))
  
  ))
server <- function(input, output,session)
{
  GlassSupplier <- c('Supplier 1','Supplier 2','Supplier 1','Supplier 4','Supplier 2')
  WindowType <- c('Wood','Vinyl','Aluminum','Aluminum','Vinyl')
  BreakageRate <- c(7.22,6.33,3.63,2,6)
  df<- data.frame(GlassSupplier,WindowType,BreakageRate)
  data <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    req(input$table)
    df %>% dplyr::filter(GlassSupplier %in% input$table) %>%
      group_by(WindowType) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(BrkRate = mean(BreakageRate))
  })
  
  #Update SelectInput Dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "table", choices = df$GlassSupplier)
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
    data()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Any particular reason to have a sidebar inside a panel as opposed to the reverse?

Comment: Actually, I just started learning R. Not sure what the best approach is

Comment: You can add another panel with another `tabsetPanel` with its title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shiny with multiple tabs and different sidebar in each tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222796/shiny-with-multiple-tabs-and-different-sidebar-in-each-tab)

Comment: Thank you so much Nelson, I have updated the question with my actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `tabsetPanel` as any other slider/button, you can insert it inside the sidebar, in the main panel, or before the `sidebarLayout`.

code for ui:

```
u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             selectInput(inputId = "table",
                                         label = "Choose a Supplier",
                                         "Names"),
                             actionButton(inputId = "btn",label="See Table"),
                             checkboxInput("donum1", "Make #1 plot", value = T),
                             checkboxInput("donum2", "Make #2 plot", value = F),
                             checkboxInput("donum3", "Make #3 plot", value = F),
                             checkboxInput("donum4", "Make #4 plot", value = F),
                             sliderInput("wt1","Weight 1",min=1,max=10,value=1),
                             sliderInput("wt2","Weight 2",min=1,max=10,value=1),
                             sliderInput("wt3","Weight 3",min=1,max=10,value=1),
                             sliderInput("wt4","Weight 4",min=1,max=10,value=1)
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel",
                          tabsetPanel(
                          tabPanel("Plot", column(6,plotOutput(outputId="plotgraph", width="500px",height="400px"))),
                          tabPanel('Table', tableOutput("myTable")))
                ))))
```